# In how many ways the number n can be represented as sum using any combinations of 1 and/or 2

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

In how many ways a number n can be represented as sum using any combinations of 1 and/or 2 ? I know answer but I don't know a good way to express the solution step by step. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Lift the restriction. For $n=0$ there is one way (the empty sum), and for $n=1$ there is one way (one summand $1$). Beyond that, you get a recursion that  leads to the Fibonacci numbers straightaway

Comment: Thank you! Edited the question to lift the restriction.

Comment: To represent $7$, for example, you may either (represent $5$ and then amend $2$) or (represent $6$ and then amend $1$). So $N(7)=N(6)+N(5)$. Etc.